# Table not adding to panel on Action

Tags: java, jtable, action

I have Jtable that I want to add to the main JFrame when a MenuItem is triggered, but the problem is that will not show.

If I add the table to panel from the beginning it shows, but I need it to show when the action occures.

Here is the main class that creates the frame(I removed several items which are not needed to be posted like creating the menubar,menu etc):

```
package gestiune;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Gestiune {
    static Gest gest;
    static Action actListaAng;    
    static JPanel panouPrinc;
    static ListaAngajati lang;
    static JMenuItem listaAng;
    static class Gest extends JFrame{
     public Gest(){                
            actListaAng = new ActListaAng("List");
            listaAng=new JMenuItem(actListaAng);
            panouPrinc = new JPanel();
            panouPrinc.setBackground(Color.white);
            Container cp = getContentPane();            
            cp.add(panouPrinc);
            pack();
            setTitle("Some title");
            setSize(1000,700);
            setLocation(0,0);
            setVisible(true);            
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gest = new Gest();
    }

    //class for listing action
    static class ActListaAng extends AbstractAction {

        public ActListaAng(String text){
            super(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lang = new ListaAngajati();
            panouPrinc.add(lang);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the table class:

```
package gestiune;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ListaAngajati extends JPanel {
    JTable tabel;
    JScrollPane panouScroll;
    public ListaAngajati() {
        panouScroll = new JScrollPane(tabel);
        String[] numeCol = {
        "Nume",
        "Prenume",
        "Categorie",
        "Data Adaugare",
        "Ultima Modificare"
    };

    Object[][] linii = {
        {"verban","adrian","sds","16-03-1989","acum"}
    };    
    tabel = new JTable(linii,numeCol);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(tabel.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(panouScroll);
    add(tabel);

    }    

}
```

I've tried several things, like using repaint on ActionEvent, or directly into the the table class......and while if I add `lang=new ListaAngajati(); panouPrinc.add(lang);` directly into the main jframe constructor works, from action it doesn't, so I kind of run out of options, so can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `revalidate()` and `repaint()` it works. You should always `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding a component during runtime.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    lang=new ListaAngajati();
    panouPrinc.add(lang);
    panouPrinc.revalidate();
    panouPrinc.repaint();
}
```

Also there was no button to click on, so I added a button here, and added the Action

```
Container cp=getContentPane(); 
JButton button = new JButton(new ActListaAng("Action"));
button.setText("Open");
cp.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
cp.add(panouPrinc);
pack();
```

Works fine.

---

As a side note, you really need go through a tutorial on `static`. You're totally overly and unnecessarily using it.

Comment: thank you for your side note, this is for a project for faculty, I am trying to get it dones as fast as I can, and will go through static tutorial.

Comment: Funny thing.......I just found an older project of mine similar to this one......and there I had all the help I needed, I thought I deleted that project from my machine, but it was there along......it sucks to have my memory.

Answer (score 1):

call updateUI() or repaint() or revalidate();  as the table is added but the UI is not getting refreshed.

Comment: Sorry,It was hard to choose which answer to set as accepted one.Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

//Global Declaration

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
private int count=0;
```

//Display only header on form load

```
//create header for the table
header = new Vector<String>();
header.add("Column1"); 
header.add("Column2");
...
model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
table = new JTable(model);
```

//in actionPerformed()

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource()==yourMenuItem){
data=get();

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Object[] d={data.get(i).get(0),data.get(i).get(1),data.get(i).get(2)};
        model.addRow(d);
}
}
    }
```

This will help you to get data from database

```
get(){
Vector<Vector<String>> doublevector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();//Your Database connection code
PreparedStatement pre1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table");

ResultSet rs1 = pre1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
Vector<String> singlevector = new Vector<String>();
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(1)); 
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(2)); 
....
doublevector.add(singlevector);
count++
}

return doublevector;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I will look into it, though as you seen my question was about the table not showing up I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: how do you get count value?except for doing another query?

Comment: count value is counted in get()